# How to install Polymer elements (and their dependencies) from the master branch?

Tags: polymer, bower

In the official Polymer documentation for elements, it's recommended to use Bower in order to install the elements and their dependencies: https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-elements.

To install the major elements, I'm using the following commands:

> bower install PolymerElements/iron-elements
>
> bower install PolymerElements/paper-elements
>
> bower install PolymerElements/app-elements
>
> bower install PolymerElements/neon-elements

This is working fine, but the installed versions of the different components are based on the latest tag available from their git repositories.

Some repositories are not often updated, and the tag can be pretty old even if some commits were applied, like for https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-listbox. In that case, the last tag is nearly one year old!

So, how can Bower be asked to download only the master branch of each dependency?

When using this command:

> bower install PolymerElements/iron-elements#master

the "iron-elements" project will be installed from the master branch, but all the dependencies are still installed with their latest tag available from their git repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give address of the master branch in your `bower.json` file.

```
"paper-card": "git@github.com:PolymerElements/paper-card.git#master"
```

Then anytime you do a `bower install` bower will fetch from master of that element's code.

Comment: In that case, I'll have to modify all the bower.json files (there are around one hundred of them!) and replace the component name by its git url: this will not be easy to do, and it's really looking like it must be something that bower must do.

Comment: There are huge downside to switching to `master`. Master's code build might be failing, which means there is possible error in master. Master might have some breaking changes which will break your code, some half implemented features, untested features or hundreds of other issues. So ideally you should not do this, specially for third party elements over which you have no control whatsoever.